# Solve Helmholtz equation without separating variables

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, partial-derivative

How to find all the twice differentiable functions $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{C}$, which satisfies the Helmholtz equation,
$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} =-k^2f$$
where $k>0$ ?

If the seperation of variables method give all the possible solutions, how can we prove it?

Comment: what solutions have you found using separation of variables?

Comment: $f(x,y)=A\sin(ax) \sin(by)$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ is a solution when $a,b,A\in\mathbb{C}$ are constants satisfying $a^2+b^2=k^2$